# Have to rmmod and modprobe every time I start up

Tags: kernel, wifi, realtek, modprobe, module

I have got a raspberry pi and I've installed it correctly the 8821cu module for my Wi-Fi Dongle and it works ok.

But every time I reboot the pi I have to `sudo rmmod 8821cu && modprobe 8821cu` to connect to my access point.

Before that the nm-applet says the device is not ready.

Output of dmesg before `rmmod and mmodprobe`

```
[    5.087767] 8821cu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  154.347730] rtl8821cu 1-1.2:1.0 wlx000f007d127a: renamed from wlan0
[  198.536962] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx000f007d127a: link is not ready
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

- A tainted kernel just means that the kernel is no longer in a state supported by the community. This is because you installed a previously not included/unsupported driver into the kernel (not an error).
- The renaming of the device (not necessarily an error).
- `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx000f007d127a: link is not ready` (not an error). Tells part of the story though.

This could be the result of a router either not supporting IPv6 or has it turned off.

However, I think what you are experiencing is a result of the onboard Ethernet and or Wifi being preconfigured in the kernel and the fact that the usb-wifi was not.

- I would debug with `ifconfig`/`iwconfig`, get the device name and setup a `/etc/network/interfaces` entry for it. You might also consider blacklisting the other device/devices if you don't intend on using them. If `ifconfig`/`iwconfig` are not installed, run `sudo apt-get install net-tools`.

Try just adding the following to /etc/networking/interfaces for that card:

```
auto nameofinterface
iface nameofinterface inet dhcp
```

You could also try the following:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
```

Referanced from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/862185/894044

*I know it is not Raspbian, but it is a Debian derivative of Linux.*